# Child not updating after Parent State changed

Tags: reactjs

I am quite new with React and I have problem bellow

I have a parent component like this:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {count:1};
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {
        return false;
    }

    setCount = () => {
        this.setState({
            count: 2
        });
    };

    render() {
        const {name, running, onRun, onStop} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <Test count={this.state.count}/>
                <p><a href="#" onClick={this.setCount}>SetCount</a></p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And here is Test component

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {
        return true;
    }
    render() {
        const {count} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {console.log("Counting")}
                <p>{count}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have method "shouldComponentUpdate" returns "false" in Parent component because I don't want to re-render it. 
My understanding is React know which part of DOM need to be re-rendered. And in this case, the state of Parent changes will re-render "Test" component

But when I run above code, "Test" component does not redender.

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate returning false in your parent component will not re-render the child once state updates.

Comment: But I thought React knows which part of DOM has to be re-rendered. If I change "shouldComponentUpdate" and return "True" or just remove it, then "Test" component alway re-rendered, but it re-rendered just because Parent's render method executed again. I want only "Test" component to be re-rendered

Comment: Yes, it knows which part of the DOM to re-render, unless you override that in the shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle, which is what you've done here.

Comment: does it mean if parent component never re-render then all it’s child will never change?

Comment: Yeah. Children can't change unless parent explicitly tells them to because of a prop change. In this case, you're never re-rendering again which causes all of its children to remain as they were from the initial render.

Comment: Well. I am a bit confused. in my code, “Test”’s props has been updated by calling “setState” from parent component.

Comment: No it hasn't. You've only updated state, but you're specifically telling your component to NEVER call the render() function again. So regardless of whether or not your state changes, the component never re-renders again, which NEVER changes the children's props.

Comment: hummm. If what you say is correct, then i thing it would be a big issue in a big application with a lot of nested component. Any thing wrong in shouldComponentUpdate method of parent component can cause entire page never updade. How to prevent it?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: Hi, can you show me a example of changing props trigger re-render? in my example if I remove “shouldComponentUpdate” from Parent component then “Test” component will be re-rendered every time of calling setState from parent no mater setState changes it’s props or not right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `true` from your parent's `shouldComponentUpdate` method.

If you return false, after the initial render it won't update, even if you call a function that calls `setState`.

Comment: Hi. I know, but i don’t want to re-render entire Parent component. I just want to update Test component.

Comment: I understand that, but when you return `false` from your parent component even on clicking `SetCount` your state does not change i.e Parent is not re-rendering. 

However your parent's state is the prop to your Test component, so when the prop has not changed your Test component will not update.

Answer (score -1):

Is the refresh of the whole page are you talking about? If thats the case, probably you wanna change your `<a>` tag to button or use `e.preventDefault();`.

If not, I am not sure if that is possible. If you setState in the parent, it will rerender parent as well as the children. If you dont want to render the parent then you have to manage individual state management in the child level.
For example,

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const {name, running, onRun, onStop} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <Test/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {count:1};
    }
    setCount = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            count: 2
        });
    };
    render() {
        const {count} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                {console.log("Counting")}
                <p>{count}</p>
                <p><a href="#" onClick={this.setCount}>SetCount</a></p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i know. I just want to understand more about “changing props from parent component to trigger re-render” as React docs mentioned